# In $\mathbb Z[x]$, show that the only common divisors of $2$ and $x$ are $1$ and $-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In $\mathbb Z[x]$, show that the only common divisors of $2$ and $x$ are $1$ and $-1$.

$\mathbb Z[x]$ is the ring of poloynomials with integer coefficients.

This should be a pretty trivial question. I'm not really sure how one shows this to be true outside of something glaringly straightforward like:

The divisors of $2$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ are $1,-1,2,$and $-2$.

The divisors of $x$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ are $1,-1,x,$ and $-x$.

Thus, the only common divisors are $1$ and $-1$.

Is there something I am missing?

As a side note, the only elements of $\mathbb Z[x]$ that have multiplicative inverses are the nonzero constants, correct?

Comment: Your side note is incorrect; 2 does not have a multiplicative inverse, for example.  The only units of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are $1,-1$.

Comment: So, the only elements of $\mathbb Z[x]$ that have multiplicative inverses are $1$ and $-1$?

Comment: That is correct, $\pm1$ are the only elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with multiplicative inverses.

Comment: @J.DavidTaylor, the idea of the OP, I suppose, is that he listed **all** the divisors of each of both $\;2\,,\,\,x\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc If the OP is confident that those are all of the divisors, then he already has his answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $\def\deg{\operatorname{deg}}\deg(pq)=\deg p+\deg q$, with the convention that $\deg 0=-\infty$ and $-\infty+k=-\infty$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{-\infty\}$; $\deg p$ denotes the degree of $p$.

Thus a divisor of $2$ must have degree $0$, so it's a constant, hence we're left with $1$, $-1$, $2$ and $-2$. Now $2$ does not divide $x$, because $2p(x)=x$ means $\deg p=1$ and a contradiction is easily reached. Thus $2$ and $-2$ do not divide $x$, from which $1$ and $-1$ are the only common divisors of $2$ and $x$.